# Как реализовать пользовательский фон?

Tags: html

Как можно реализовать пользовательский фон? Допустим, что посетитель сайт зашёл на сайт, выбрал картинку у себя на компьютере, которую он хочет сделать фоном на сайте, и она без всяких загрузок на сервер отображалась только у него?

Comment: css+javascript.

Comment: Цветухин Михаил, можно пример?

Comment: Я лучше расскажу. Предлагаем пользователю добавить картинку. Потом с помощью java создаем стиль css, который добавляет background-image. Готово: картинка отображается как фон.

Comment: @Цветухин Михаил, также можно название картинки или путь к ней хранить в куках, чтобы при последующих заходах скрипт знал какой фон ему подставлять. Или даже в базе путь хранить

Answer (score 1):

Да, если у вас есть БД с пользователями, то загружаете картинку на серв, в бд в строчке например usr_background  прописываете путь к этой картинке на серве, а затем при рендеринге странице с помощью  PHP вставьте эту ссылку на страницу то есть вот так:

```
<html>       
<head>
  <style>
  body {
      background: url(<?=$usr_background;//в эту переменную запихните вывод url картинки из бд?>); 
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
...
```